# Conway Game Of Life - How to detect Evolution has stopped

Tags: python, multidimensional-array, conways-game-of-life

I've gotten the Conway Game of Life in Python 3.9 from [git-hub](https://github.com/Josephbakulikira/Conway-s-Game-of-life---Python) (there's also a great video on youtube [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=d73z8U0iUYE), made by the author)

All works fine.

Now I'd like to auto-detect when the evolution gets stuck, that is when the cell and cell group shapes are all static or regular oscillators (see pics attached at the end of this post).

My first idea was to compare the next generation grid backwards to 4 generations, that is: if the next generation grid is equal to ny of the previous four generation then it's safe to assume that the evolution has stopped.

So I first thought to make copies of the last 4 grids in 4x2D indipendent arrays and compare at each passage the **next** generation with each of them.

What would be the most efficient (in terms of time lag) way to compare two bidimentional arrays with say 400 columns and 200 rows?

The scripts use pygame.
here is a copy of what I am using (my plan is to use the ***check_if_over*** function in the grid.py module to return True if the evolution has stopped).

MAIN MODULE:

```
modules = ["pygame", "numpy", "ctypes"]

import sys
import importlib
import subprocess


def install(package):
    # install packages if needed
    subprocess.check_call([sys.executable, "-m", "pip", "install", package])

# check for needed pacjakes/modules
for needed_module in modules:
    try:
        i = importlib.import_module(needed_module)
        print(f"{needed_module} successfully imported")
    except ImportError as e:
        install(needed_module)
        i = importlib.import_module(needed_module)
    except:
        "Something went wrong"

import pygame
import os
import grid
import ctypes
from pygame.locals import *

## ADJUSTABLE PARMAS
reduction_factor = 2        # reduces the  width/height of the window vs screen size
fps = 60                    # max frames per second
scaler = 5                  # scales down, the smaller the scaler the greater the number of cells
offset = 1                 # thickness of grid separator, must be < scaler

#### COLORS
black = (0, 0, 0)
white = (255, 255, 255)
blue = (0, 14, 71)

os.environ["SDL_VIDEO_CENTERED"] = '1'
user32 = ctypes.windll.user32
screensize = user32.GetSystemMetrics(0), user32.GetSystemMetrics(1)

width, height = int(screensize[0]/reduction_factor), int(screensize[1]/reduction_factor)
size = (width, height)
pygame.init()
pygame.display.set_caption("Conway Game of Life")
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size)
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
Grid = grid.Grid(width, height, scaler, offset)
Grid.random2d_array()

run = True
# game loop
while run:
    clock.tick(fps)
    screen.fill(black)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT:
            run = False
    Grid.Conway(off_color=white, on_color=blue, surface=screen)
    pygame.display.update()
pygame.quit()
exit(0)
```

grid.py:

```
import pygame
import numpy as np
import random

class Grid:
    def __init__(self, width, height, scale, offset):
        self.scale = scale
        self.columns = int(height / scale)
        self.rows = int(width / scale)
        self.size = (self.rows, self.columns)
        self.grid_array = np.ndarray(shape=(self.size))
        # next 3 lines defines the set of array copies to save
        # the past 4 generations 
        self.grid_array_copies = []
        for i in range(0, 4):
            self.grid_array_copies.append(np.ndarray(shape=(self.size)))
        self.offset = offset
        self.alive = 0
        self.evolution_stopped = False


    def random2d_array(self):
        for x in range(self.rows):
            for y in range(self.columns):
                self.grid_array[x][y] = random.randint(0, 1)

    def Conway(self, off_color, on_color, surface):
        for x in range(self.rows):
            for y in range(self.columns):
                y_pos = y * self.scale
                x_pos = x * self.scale

                if self.grid_array[x][y] == 1:
                    pygame.draw.rect(surface, on_color, [x_pos, y_pos, self.scale - self.offset, self.scale - self.offset])
                else:
                    pygame.draw.rect(surface, off_color, [x_pos, y_pos, self.scale - self.offset, self.scale - self.offset])
        next = np.ndarray(shape=(self.size))
        self.alive = 0
        for x in range(self.rows):
            for y in range(self.columns):
                state = self.grid_array[x][y]
                neighbours = self.get_neighbours(x, y)
                if state == 0 and neighbours == 3:
                    next[x][y] = 1
                    self.alive += 1
                elif state == 1 and (neighbours < 2 or neighbours > 3):
                    next[x][y] = 0
                else:
                    next[x][y] = state
                    self.alive += state
                    
        self.grid_array = next
        self.check_if_over(next)
        with open("survivors.txt", "w") as f:
            f.write(str(self.alive))

    def get_neighbours(self, x, y):
        total = 0
        for n in range(-1, 2):
            for m in range(-1, 2):
                x_edge = (x + n + self.rows) % self.rows
                y_edge = (y + m + self.columns) % self.columns
                total += self.grid_array[x_edge][y_edge]

        total -= self.grid_array[x][y]
        return total

    def check_if_over(self, next):
        pass
```

Thanx for the patience.
Initial conditions:
[image]
Evolution stopped:
[image]

***EDIT***

I forgot to mention something that may be not that straightforward.
Unlike Golly (another open source for the Conway's Game of Life), the environment where this Game of Life plays is a finite one (see pictures above), that is it's kinda rendering of a spherical suface into a rectangle, so the cells colonies evolving past the right edge of the window re-enter at the left edge, those at the bottom edge re-enter at the top. While in Golly, for example the plan environment is theoretically infinite.

Golly starting conditions, zoomed in:
[image]

Golly starting conditions partially zoomed out (could go futher out until cells invisibility and further). The black surface is the environment, the white squares the cells
[image]

Comment: Save the grid to a prior_grid and if the two are equal on the next iteration then evolution has stopped. Alternatively, for each iteration track if you needed to update the grid and if you did evolution is still happening. Note, please don't use `next` as a variable name and you will shoot yourself in the foot.

Comment: it can be big problem to recognize `regular oscillators`. First idea: remeber previous grids and comare if current grid is similar to one of previous grid. But problem is when you have few oscillators which can oscillate with different speed - it would need somehow split grid to separated objects and check every object separatelly. And this can be big problem to split it. maybe it is problem for [DataScience](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: @JonSG. good point about `next`. Unfortunately saving just the previous grid won't work. At the end of the evolutionary stage, the game will have created **oscillators** (cells that oscillates between 2 shapes without evolving) that will go on indefintely.

Comment: @furas. yes, you are spot on. I was thinking about creating masks of static groups of cells and oscillators to superimpose to the next grid, but I am a bit confused about the way to proceed afterward.

Comment: I have two ideas: (1) use `Computer Vision` to detect shapes - see [OpenCV shape detection](https://pyimagesearch.com/2016/02/08/opencv-shape-detection/) but it needs external modules. And it needs to learn something totally new. (2) get single pixel, if it black then check other pixels in nebourhood and add black pixels to collection - and repeating this for added pixels (using recursion) you can find all pixels which creates one object. If you repeate it for all pixels then you should find al objects. If some pixel belong to object then don't use it again to search next object.

Comment: @furas: good hints. I'll explore them and let you know

Comment: The other issue is how to deal with gliders?